# Why @FormParam does not support content=type=application/json?

Tags: java, rest, postman

I have tested a Rest API using postman and while testing on selection raw option, it shows unsupported media for application/json header content type, but only working with url-encoded form. Please specify how to use `@FormParam` for `application/json` content type. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The `@FormParam` annotation is only used to access parameters passed in a normal form that usually uses `x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you're sending your data as a JSON in request body, you can just create a POJO class corresponding to your request body containing all properties of your JSON request and use it as the parameter of your REST method. The JAX-RS container automatically deserializes the JSON body of the request into the given object for you.

As an example, if your request body is something like this:

```
{
    "firstName" : "Foo",
    "lastName"  : "bar"
}
```

Then you can define a POJO representing your request data as below:

```
public class PersonRequest {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And define your REST endpoint to access this data as:

```
@POST
@Path("/persons")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String savePerson(PersonRequest personRequestData) {
    // request data are deserialized into the personRequestDataas properties 
    System.out.println(personRequestData.getFirstName());

}
```

You don't need to specify any sort of annotation on your POJO class.

Comment: Thanks, so using this approach I can test my API using applicantion/json media type instead of  application/x-www-form-urlencoded right? As i want to test it using applicantion/json in Json type request body using raw option.

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam what if I want to support both json and urlencoded? how do I do that?

Comment: @Kousha It's not easy. You can put an extra @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) on top of the same method, but the injected parameter would be either null or an exception rises. If it becomes null, then inside method you can read parameters from request object or personRequestData object (based on mime type). Another option could be to remove all parameters from your method and try accessing request parameters/body directly based on the request mime-type. Maybe would be better to have two separate method for that and let JAX-RS handle all unmarshalling process for you.